# MYSQL returning incomplete results

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table called books with following data:

```
id | description | section
 1 | textbook 1  |  1
 2 | textbook 2  |  1
 3 | textbook 3  |  1
```

I use the following query to select id 2 and the next and previous rows in section 1:

```
SELECT id FROM books where id IN
(2,
(SELECT id FROM books WHERE id < 2 LIMIT 1),
(SELECT id FROM books WHERE id > 2 LIMIT 1)
)
AND section = 1
```

When I add the `section = 1`, the query returns only id 2 while it should return all the 3 ids but when I remove this part it selects all the 3 ids. My scheme is actually more complex than that but I simplified it to explain the situation. So, what am I doing wrong above?

Comment: You're missing parts of your query.

Comment: Is that the full statement, or does that appear in an "IN" clause?

Comment: Your `IN` condition as written does not make *any* sense.

Comment: Does ID autoincrement?

Comment: yes it's autoincrement

Comment: @MichaelSamuel so why you can't calculate ID's before querying? If u looking for 2, then you know, that you need 1 and 3 as well

Comment: @Uriil 1 and 3 might be in a different section.

Comment: it's autoincrement but not arranged ascending or descending ids...it's arranged according to other columns not states above for simplicity...i want to know what's wrong with the above code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(SELECT id
FROM books
WHERE id < 2 and section = 1
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1)

UNION 

(SELECT id
FROM books
WHERE id >= 2 and section = 1
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 2)
```

The problem with your query is that you're picking random ids less than 2 and greater than 2, without taking the section into account. If those IDs aren't in section 1, they won't be included in the result.

The WHERE clause in your outer query is not distributed into the subqueries. The subqueries are executed independently, returning IDs, which are put into the `IN` clause. Then the outer query filters by section.

[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ea22/3)

Comment: this should work but I want to know what's wrong with my subqueries? thanks :)

Comment: Added explanation to the answer.

Comment: but they are actually in section 1 as stated in the scheme :)

Comment: isn't `AND section=1` selects the rows if they are in section 1 which they actually do..so why it wouldn't work??

Comment: You're filtering on `section` _after_ you select the `id`, not using it as a criteria to select the `id`. And `id > 2` could select `id = 50`, not `id = 3`, because you don't have `ORDER BY`.

Comment: I just noticed something: you're working with two different tables, `books` and `ecards`. But you only showed the `books` table. How are these tables related?

Comment: sorry Barmar that was a mistake I have books only table..corrected it

Comment: isn't adding the `AND section=1` to the code applies the criteria to all selected ids including those in the subquery??

Comment: No, the subqueries are executed first, and then the outer query's WHERE clause applies to the result.

Comment: yup :) got you! Solved it by adding the filtering with section inside the subqueries as well like the outer query...thanks very much

Comment: You don't need it in the outer query if you already did it in the inner queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id FROM books where id IN
(2,
(SELECT id FROM books WHERE id < 2 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1),
(SELECT id FROM books WHERE id > 2 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1)
)
AND section = 1
```

The `ORDER BY` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this solves your problem:

```
SELECT id
FROM books
WHERE id IN
(2
, ((SELECT id FROM books WHERE id < 2 AND section = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1))
, ((SELECT id FROM books WHERE id > 2 AND section = 1 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1))
)
AND section = 1
```